# Flutter Form onSaved execution order with nested custom FormFields

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom `FormField<String>` MyFancyTextFormField which just wraps a TextFormField with some extras.

I want to use this FormField by itself, but I wanted to use it inside another FormField too: TextList which is just basically a column filled with MyFancyTextFormFields.

I came up with this:

```dart
class FirstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => FirstWidgetState();
}

class FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> initial = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  List<String> modified;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Form(
            key: _form,
            child: TextList(initialValue: initial, onSaved: (values) => print('TextList saved with: ${modified = values}')),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Save'),
            onPressed: () {
              _form.currentState.save();
              print('Initial value was: $initial, modified value is: $modified');
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextList extends FormField<List<String>> {
  TextList({List<String> initialValue, FormFieldSetter<List<String>> onSaved})
      : super(
            initialValue: initialValue,
            onSaved: onSaved,
            builder: (state) {
              //Make a copy
              List<String> _value = List.of(state.value);
              //This just creates the list of MyFancyTextFormField
              List<Widget> fields = _value
                  .asMap()
                  .map<int, Widget>((i, val) => MapEntry(
                      i,
                      MyFancyTextFormField(
                          initialValue: _value[i],
                          onSaved: (val) {
                            print('MyFancyTextFormField[$i] saved with $val');
                            state.didChange(_value..replaceRange(i, i + 1, [val]));
                          })))
                  .values
                  .toList();
              return Column(
                children: fields,
              );
            });
}

class MyFancyTextFormField extends FormField<String> {
  MyFancyTextFormField({
    String initialValue,
    FormFieldSetter<String> onSaved,
  }) : super(
            initialValue: initialValue,
            onSaved: (value) => onSaved(value),
            builder: (state) => TextFormField(
                  initialValue: initialValue,
                  onSaved: onSaved,
                ));
}
```

The problem with this is that, when I save() the Form State, the framework will save my top level FormField TextList first before my leaf-level FormField MyFancyTextFormField.

This is my output:

```
I/flutter (  615): TextList saved with: [one, two, three]
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[0] saved with one
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[0] saved with oneee
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[1] saved with two
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[1] saved with two
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[2] saved with three
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[2] saved with threeeeeeeeee
I/flutter (  615): Initial value was: [one, two, three], modified value is: [one, two, three]
```

Since after the first execution of save(), my TextList's State is correctly updated, if I run save() again I will have my expected output:

```
I/flutter (  615): TextList saved with: [oneee, two, threeeeeeeeee]
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[0] saved with one
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[0] saved with oneee
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[1] saved with two
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[1] saved with two
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[2] saved with three
I/flutter (  615): MyFancyTextFormField[2] saved with threeeeeeeeee
I/flutter (  615): Initial value was: [one, two, three], modified value is: [oneee, two, threeeeeeeeee]
```

Why are MyFancyTextFormField(s)'s onSaved called twice?

Is there a way to have my expected result, better than recall state.save() as many times as my FormField's tree height?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late answer, but I think it's because `MyFancyTextFormField` extends `FormField` as well as returns an additional `TextFormField` in the builder. If you turn `MyFancyTextFormField` into a Stateless Widget that returns a `TextFormField` you'll get what you want:

```
class MyFancyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialValue;
  final FormFieldSetter<String> onSaved; 

   MyFancyTextFormField({
    this.initialValue,
    this.onSaved,  
  }) ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        initialValue: initialValue,
        onSaved: this.onSaved);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's always useful to watch again problems I couldn't wrap around. That's actually a good point. I can't remember if I had any particular reason why `MyFancyTextFormField` should have extended `FormField` (if is there any plausible reason). I'll watch again my code.